# JSON REST without using WCF

Tags: android, wcf

Is there any way I can send a JSON using REST with out using a WCF from .NET? The purpose is to send a string from the android mobile client to .NET server, append a string and send it back to the android client. The search only yielded me with SOAP which is not recommended for efficiency matters.

Comment: You can use .asmx service, but now wcf is more popular today. WCF also supports Restful JSON request.

Comment: Can you please point to a link, does .asmx support Restfull json? If yes how can I call the service from my android client?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Service Stack](http://www.servicestack.net/). Does JSON over REST.

Answer (score 0):

**(Android)Client side :**

```
public String SendToWebFunc(List<NameValuePair> postParameters, String URL)
{
HttpClient client1 = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost request = new HttpPost(URL);  
String page="";   
try 
{
  request.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParameters));
  UrlEncodedFormEntity formEntity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParameters);
  request.setEntity(formEntity);
  HttpResponse response;
  response = client1.execute(request);  //Sends the actual request

  //Decode response to string
  BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new     InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
  String line1;
  line1 = in.readLine();

  while(line1!=null)
  {
    page=page+line1;
        line1=in.readLine();
  }

 }           
 catch (ClientProtocolException e) 
 {
            e.printStackTrace();
 } catch (IOException e)   {
            e.printStackTrace();
 }  
 return page;   
}
```

you can have url as

```
http://IP_Address/Login/Register.ashx
```

At Server ashx service:

```
public class Register : IHttpHandler
{

    public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context)
    {
        String data = context.Request.Params["request_data"];

        .
        .
        .
        context.Response.Write("false");
    }
}
```

Comment: What if I need to send some thing back to the client?